# Singleton class losing properties in specific scope

Tags: typescript

I have a strange bug happening a couple times in a large project, using VSC.

I have a singleton class referencing a bunch of classes, some of those classes have reference to that singleton class. Twice during the development of that project I had 2 of those classes that completely lost the singleton class properties and methods at runtime.

For example I would do (let's say singleton class is A):

In class C:

```
A.someMethod()//no problem
```

In class D:

```
A.someMethod()//error A is an object but has no properties or method
```

In class E:

```
A.someMethod();//no problem
```

So for some reason within the scope of D, A is an empty object.

This happened for 2 classes, each time I fixed it by removing all reference of those classes anywhere in the project, then renaming the module of those classes, commenting out all code in those classes, then renaming the module correctly, compile and then all is fixed, I can add back references of those classes and restore the code and now the singleton class reference is not empty anymore.

So this is strange, anyone has any experience with that? Is it a compiler bug or some Javascript weirdness?

Alright I did try with small classes and I reach same problem:

```
class A
{
    constructor()
    {
        new B();
        C;
    }

    public static getClassA():A
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

If B and C do have references to A then that reference to A is an empty object (not even a class). Apparently same happens if B and C are referenced by a static method of A (so it's not just a constructor thing). Not sure about member method yet. Even though I don't instantiate C the C class runs into same problem.

Update on this: The problem is any class that references in constructor another class (one way or another) and that other class references in any way directly that first class (import, static, instantiation, etc ...) find that first class completely empty at runtime, all properties/methods either member or static are just gone.

Comment: I think you need to add code that shows the flow of your appliciation: when do you instantiate class c,d,e? What does A look like, and how did you implement the singleton?

Comment: That's a lot of code, I'll see if I can reproduce it with simple classes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't get much interest so here's what I found as an answer.

Situation:

Class A does reference in constructor class B.
Class B does reference class A (in any way)

Consequence:

Then inside Class B, class A is empty and has no properties or methods either member or static.

Solution:

The only solution I found is to make sure any class referencing any other class is not itself referenced by those classes.